# Read contents of a Text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a text box created but how would I get the input to a function.

```
userbox = Text(root, width = 10, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
userbox.pack()

passwordbox = Text(root, width = 10, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
passwordbox.pack()

b2 = Button(root,text="Submit Login")
b2.pack()
b2.configure(command=login)
```

How would I get this to be processed. I.E. if the username = "name" and the password = "password" `print "welcome"` if not `print"incorrect login"`

Comment: You really should use the [`Entry` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@BurhanKhalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474899/read-contents-of-a-text-box#comment37881330_24474899) points out, you should use the [`Tk.Entry()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget for things like this. Assuming you were using the [`Tk.Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget you can get the text of the widget using the [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) attribute.

Code:

```
def login():
    if userbox.get() == "name" and passwordbox.get() == "password":
        print "welcome"
    else:
        print"incorrect login"

userbox = Entry(root, width = 10)
userbox.pack()

passwordbox = Entry(root, width = 10)
passwordbox.pack()

b2 = Button(root,text="Submit Login")
b2.pack()
b2.configure(command=login)
```